# Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" won't work with URL shortener CTA button

Tags: .htaccess, x-frame-options

I want to use a url shortener CTA (Call-To-Action) button. I was told for the CTA to work with my site, I had to disable:
`Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"`
in my .htaccess file.

This option was set by my security software.

The url shortener worked after I commented out that line.

I also had to add a url to my CNAME (lets say `link.shorten.click`) in the DNS to make this work - that was part of the instructions.

But, is there a way to keep the security while allowing this CTA button to work, like making some exception? Not sure if the CNAME url can be used for the exception as I don't know what it does.

I'm just including it in case it helps.

I just sent a note to the developer / owner of the url shortener. But, it was just now. I thought I would post here as well.

### Background of this url shortener

I just want to add what this url shortener CTA button does and how it works in case it helps. So, in my login with the 3rd-party dashboard, I create a link. I did it on a subdomain: click.example.com/dd3id

And that link will redirect a user to the target, let's say: www.example.com.

And then a "pop-up" box will slide in with whatever message I added.

And that's what this url shortener CTA box does.

Answer (score 1):

If the CTA button on your side is in an iframe on a different side, it does not make sense to restrict access.
Just make sure you don't disable `SAMEORIGIN` for URLs not related to the CTA.

I think you can use the Apache `<Location />` directive for that.

If you only want to allow a specific site to use your CTA, restrict the access via `X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://example.com/`.

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

See this Q/A and use it to conditionally set the headers according to your URLs:

https://serverfault.com/questions/740433/set-header-based-on-request-uri

Comment: Thanks @daniel-w . It almost worked when I allowed it from my subdomain: click.example.com. The pop-up showed up, but, I got a 500 error for the destination page (which does actually load fine). I looked up the location directive, but, I just can't follow any of that. Anything else you can add? I explained how it works a bit more in case that helps.

Comment: @linstar what is the iframe `src` domain like, and what domain is arround the iframe? The CTA you are talking about is an `<iframe>` or `<script>` tag (which produces an iframe probably), right?

Comment: I'm going to send your questions to the app owner. and get back to you. I don't quite understand or know the answers these questions.

Comment: @linstar you can look this up in the sourcecode. How do you embed the CTA? It's dangerous messing with security setting when you don't even know basic about the stuff you pull into your website.

Comment: For now, I've just bought another domain with the same name but .net extension that will serve the click tracking. That way I don't need to worry about the security. Thanks for everyone's help. I just don't know enough about this stuff and can't spend too much time on this kind of issue at the moment.